# How to handle "AttributeSet" on third party android view's constructor

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a view built by a third party, that has only one constructor. This constructor takes a context and and "IAttributeset". From my googling, I found out that attributeset is used for layout when the view is declared in xml.
But, since I'm implementing this view in code, and I;m creating a Xamarin Forms custom renderer, I had to instantiate it.
When I created an instance, I set the attributeset to null. The view appears properly once, but when I navigate out and come back to the page, the view throws an exception of type

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference'

So, I decided to create a class that inherits from IAttributeset and pass an instance of this class to the constructor.
Here is the class I created:

```
public class Attributes : Java.Lang.Object, IAttributeSet
{
    public int AttributeCount => 0;

    public string ClassAttribute => null;

    public string IdAttribute => null;

    public string PositionDescription => null;

    public int StyleAttribute => 0;

    public void Disposed()
    {
    }

    public void DisposeUnlessReferenced()
    {
    }

    public void Finalized()
    {
    }

    public bool GetAttributeBooleanValue(int index, bool defaultValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool GetAttributeBooleanValue(string @namespace, string attribute, bool defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public float GetAttributeFloatValue(int index, float defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public float GetAttributeFloatValue(string @namespace, string attribute, float defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeIntValue(int index, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeIntValue(string @namespace, string attribute, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeListValue(int index, string[] options, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeListValue(string @namespace, string attribute, string[] options, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public string GetAttributeName(int index)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeNameResource(int index)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeResourceValue(int index, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeResourceValue(string @namespace, string attribute, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeUnsignedIntValue(int index, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetAttributeUnsignedIntValue(string @namespace, string attribute, int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public string GetAttributeValue(int index)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public string GetAttributeValue(string @namespace, string name)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int GetIdAttributeResourceValue(int defaultValue)
    {
        return default;
    }

    public void SetJniIdentityHashCode(int value)
    {
        
    }

    public void SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates value)
    {
    }

    public void SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference reference)
    {
    }
}
```

This is how I passed it to the constructor

```
var radaeePdfThumbView = new PDFThumbView(Context, new Attributes());
```

But the problem is that when I run the page containing this view, I get the following error:

> Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'crc6426a1e8c58eda40cb.Attributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser'

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue please ?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but I can tell you that the error message means implementing `IAttributeset` on your own class won't work. The code is expecting an internal java class `android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser`. An Android custom renderer is `xamarin.android` code, and can work with `xml` resources, like any android app. Research how to define (as an xml resource file) and inflate an xml layout, in xamarin.android.

Comment: just to be clear, you mean I should define in an XML file the control I want to render, then get it from the xml file before rendering ?

Comment: I would say "yes", but you need to get the details right. Read about Android, and how to define and inflate layouts. google `xamarin android layout xml`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that